# Finding a Group Isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am confused on how to find an isomorphism of $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})/H$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. $H$ is the subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}, +)$ generated by $[2]_4$ 
So this means that the elements in $H$ are ${0,2}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:  The underlying set of $(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})/H$ can be denoted $$\{0+H,1+H\}$$ and the underlying set of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ can be denoted $$\{0,1\}.$$

So they are both groups of order $2$.  So any isomorphism must map the identity element in one group to the identity element in the other group (actually, this part is true for group isomorphism in general), and the non-identity element in one group to the non-identity element in the other group.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the map $[0] \mapsto [0], [1] \mapsto [1], [2] \mapsto [0], [3] \mapsto [1]$ from $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Show that it is a surjective group homomorphism, find its kernel and then use the first isomorphism theorem.